What options are there to reattach/replace this pad?

This pad came off while I was desoldering a PLCC chip. I still have the pad.
As you can see I was able to scrape away to expose the via the pad was connected to and get a blob of solder onto it. I tried using some quick setting epoxy that I had (https://www.amazon.com/J-B-Weld-50132-Clear-Adhesive/dp/B009EU5ZMK) to try to reattach the pad, but even after letting it cure for 24 hours, it broke down from the heat when I went to try to bridge the pad to the via. Incidentally, bridging to the via wasn't working well either, I think it was slightly too big of a gap for the solder to cross.
I saw that in this video they use a high temp two part epoxy to reattach a pad, but it appears that this product isn't made anymore.
I would try to run a bodge wire instead, but I need to attach a socket here (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/649-69802-432LF) and I'm imagining it would be pretty challenging to try to bodge underneath the socket.

Are you suggesting to solder the new PLCC chip directly? I'd prefer to solder a socket if possible, since this is an eprom that I need to be able to easily remove and reprogram. I linked the PLCC socket I have in the original post.

No, don't solder to the chip, solder to the PLCC socket. Never cut wires after soldering, instead measure how long they need to be in advance, then peel & pre-apply solder. Multi-strand wire is generally recommended and then you always need to pre-apply solder.

You can glue the pad to the board with with a high-temperature epoxy such as JB Weld epoxy which has a max working temp of 287°C (550°F). Don't use the quick-setting version as the temperature rating is lower.
After the epoxy sets, use a fine wire or copper tape from the via to the pad to bridge the gap. You'll need to place a dab of glue on the wire bridge to keep it in place whilst soldering the device pin to the pad.
JB Weld epoxy is available at hardware stores in North America and probably in the UK and EU.

Is this the 550°F epoxy you're referring to?

@Mars I generally buy this. Get twice the product for a bit less money than the one you linked to. Plus, I go to the local hardware store since I like to support local businesses.

Sure, I'd buy it locally if I can, I was using a convenient amazon link. You use steel reinforced epoxy? Any risk of that being conductive?

@Mars It is a loaded epoxy (glass oxide according to MSDS). It is an insulator per their web site FAQ section.

Reporting back that this worked well. After fully curing, the repaired pad even seemed to be able to tolerate short touches of the soldering iron set to 350°C. Small amounts of the epoxy did get smeared onto the neighboring pads, but it easily came off with flux and more solder.

Given it's the third pin in, and the style of the socket you want to use  you may be overthinking this.
The via is just inside the pad, which should be accessible through the gap in the connectors base:

If it is slightly under the plastic edge, you can trim that back using a knife or file without too much issue.
Once the rest of the pins are soldered, you should then be able to solder from the top the metal pin of the connector to the via, either with a solder blob or a strand of copper wire.

Alternatively it is possible to solder a wire (approximately AVG30) on top of the spring part of the socket without interfering with the connection to the IC. I've done that in the past when repairing PLCC stuff. But then you need to investigate where the trace goes and solder it to the trace destination, or to the trace itself through the scratched-off solder mask.

You can't glue it down, the only way you can attach pads after the fact is solder. Any kind of glue rated for plastic will likely not have the temperature rating for soldering and will melt. You might be able to use a high temperature epoxy, but who knows if you could get it to adhear to the FR4.
Your choices are solder and wire for bonding of broken pads.
You could solder the pad on with some blue wire and then put the part on last, make sure you use lots of flux.
Another option that I have used for parts that have small pads with blue wire is to coat the connect wire with solder and use that to bridge the gap underneath the pad.
Another option might be to use copper tape and solder that in the place of the pad, but that would be really difficult to do.
